# How do I fix the font and icon size on Notepad++ for Wine on Ubuntu?

Tags: wine, icons, fonts, dpi, notepad-plus-plus

I installed Wine on Ubuntu for the sole purpose of running Notepad++ on Ubuntu, but the GUI fonts and icons are so small they are unreadable.

Below is a full screenshot of my 75" screen (TV as monitor):
[image]

As you can see, the GUI font and icon sizes make it basically unusable.

I installed Wine using `snap`. I found that it could also be installed using `apt`, so I did a test `wine` install using that, but the only version of Notepad++ using `apt` version of `wine` is 6.x.x, which is only 32 bit and way too old, and I cannot install any plugins or upgrade it.

I tried changing the DPI setting using a `snap` instance of the `winecfg` tool, but it has no effect on my `snap` instance of Notepad++. I also found a number of versions of `wine` and `winecfg`:

- /snap/wine-platform-3-stable
- /snap/wine-platform-5-stable
- /snap/wine-platform-6-stable
- /snap/wine-platform-7-devel-core20
- /snap/wine-platform-runtime
- /snap/wine-platform-runtime-core20

I am not sure why these are all installed, nor am I sure which instance is being 'used' by `/snap/notepad-plus-plus`.

Any help on which `wine` instance is used and how to fix the Notepad++ GUI font and icon size would be gratefully received.